# Is there a way to quantify uncertainty in classification?

Tags: data-science-model, scoring, confidence, uncertainty

I'm thinking of a way to build an extension to a binary classifier (actually I will get the output probabilities like in logistic regression, so technically you should call this regression) that outputs a confidence score about how "sure you are that this is the right prediction".
I read about conformal quantile prediction and that achieves the scores with an 1-alpha confidence interval, I desire to get the opposite, given the confidence interval or the prediction, how much sure you are that the prediction is correct?
For example, to put it in a fancy way: "Since we have a lot of observations similar to this one that you are trying to predict, you should be very confident in your prediction" o "We never saw an observation like this one in training data, so you should not rely on this prediction very much". Am I clear?

If you did not get the idea yet. Here's an idea that comes to my mind right now:
For example, when it comes to decision trees. You could build a confidence score based on the fact that your observation falls under a leaf with 10000 observations or i.e 20% of the sample (assuming you have 50k for training), so if that is the case you should be more confident than if your predicted observation would fall in a leave that has 100 observations (0.1% of the training sample).
My goal is to do the same but for  gradient based boosting trees (GBDT). Doing the same for the  GBDT could be possible, but when the number of estimators grows it could get more complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: What stops you from simulating the size of prediction intervals using conformal prediction for a number of confidence levels 1 - alpha and selecting the one you need. https://github.com/valeman/awesome-conformal-prediction

Comment: When trying inductive conformal prediction:
Say my interval size is S=100 at confidence 1-alpha=0.9
Want a smaller interval? Then sacrifize confidence, ok . So S=50 conf=0.8, say that is optimimal . So for every prediction I can assure than pred-S/2<pred<pred+S/2 , good but I still can't benefit from the fact that from some cases I have 100 observations that fall in the "leaf" or 10k obs . Intuitively I would like to say that I'm more confident to say that my interval is OK when I have 10k obs similar than when I have 100.

Comment: Let's say I try conformalized quantile regression with GBMs, since it will probably benefit from the data size: 
Here S (size) is variable and I need this to be fixed. I would like to say for given fixed size S
what's the confidence behind.
I'm new to this kind of confidence /uncertainty problems, so I might be loosing something.
I will check the link you sent though and probably I will be able to find something useful. Thanks.